# Merge dataframes but without intersecting values from the right dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A and B

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a'=[1,2,3,4,5], 'b'=[11,22,33,44,55]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a'=[7,2,3,4,9], 'b'=[123,234,456,789,1122]})
```

I want to merge B and A such that I don't want the common values in column 'a' in A and B from B, only non-intersecting values from B in column 'a' should be taken. The final dataframe should look like

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 33 |
| 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 7 | 123 |
| 9 | 1122 |

Comment: If your key is a single column, you could also use `set()` and set less operation.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *"don't want the common values in column 'a' in A and B from B"*. Does your merge-on column include B or not? Is it ['A','B'] or just 'A'? Can you at least write pseudocode for what the pd.merge/join call would look like?

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is unique-valued in both `A` and `B` (some sort of unique ID for example), you can try with `concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates('a')
```

Output:

```
   a     b
0  1    11
1  2    22
2  3    33
3  4    44
4  5    55
0  7   123
4  9  1122
```

In the general case, use `isin` to check for existence of `B['a']` in `A['a']`:

```
pd.concat([A,B[~B['a'].isin(A['a'])])
```

Comment: QH's answer is too good and this isn't as good for the OP.  HOWEVER, people often use columns as an index when they should just put it in the index.  In this case, if they had put column `'a'` in the index, they could've used the method `combine_first`.  Like so: `A.set_index('a').combine_first(B.set_index('a'))`